# mitigation of grub attacks

Tags: 14.04, grub2, security

I want to disable the sing user mode attack performed at the grub level by passing kernel parameters.

I know a solution that is putting the grub password & bios password.but I want to know without putting a password can't we disable single user mode attack.

Answer (score 1):

If the attacker has physical access to system, which they need to change the kernel parameters, it's a lost cause without encryption.

However, I *guess* you can limit that particular method (`init=/arbitrary/command`), by commenting out these lines in [the kernel source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/init/main.c#L952), and compiling your own kernel:

```
if (execute_command) {
    ret = run_init_process(execute_command);
    if (!ret)
        return 0;
    panic("Requested init %s failed (error %d).",
          execute_command, ret);
}
```

I haven't tested it, so no guarantees.

Related:

- [Why does Linux allow `init=/bin/bash`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34462/why-does-linux-allow-init-bin-bash)
- [Red hat mailing list discussion](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2005-March/msg04090.html)

Answer (score 0):

Short of entirely encrypting your root partition (with a separate boot partition obviously) there's very little you could do to prevent an attack by someone who has physical access to your system.

Physical access==root access.

Comment: that means we cannot provide a best security at physical level.